# Using Submodules with a private repository for teams

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I am trying to use submodules on a project that multiple people will be working on.

The repository is private and hosted on bitbucket. There are several people that have access to the repositories and their submodules. I have used the ssh key for cloning (`git@bitbucket.org:<owner>/<repo>.git`).

When a person (not me) tries to clone the repository they are prompted to enter my SSH key. If they don't it fails.

How can I use submodules for a private repository that is shared by a team?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you have them setup their own SSH Key for the Bitbucket account.

If they clone using the HTTPS link, it will prompt them for the password but the submodules ask for the SSH Key. This is why it fails.

Comment: You can mark your answer so that it can help others who have similar questions.